# Drag & Drop with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop, draggable

There is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title> Mrb. :) </title>
    <style>
        h1{
            text-align: center;
        }
        #finishImage { 
            width:64px; 
            height:64px; 
            }
        #palette{
            position: absolute; 
            height: 535px; 
            border: 1px solid orangered; 
            top: 10px; 
            left: 10px; 
            right: 1125px;
        }
        #content{
            position: absolute; 
            height: 400px; 
            border: 1px solid black; 
            top: 135px; 
            left: 250px; 
            right: 10px;
        }
        #header{
            position: absolute;
            height: 115px;
            border: 1px solid orange;
            left: 250px;
            right: 10px;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>   
    <div id="parent">
        <div id="header">
            <h1>HEADER</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="palette">
            <h1>PALETTE</h1>
            <hr>
                <div class="tbutton"><img id="finishImage" src="finish.png" /></div>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
    </script> 
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $("#finishImage").draggable({ 
                    helper: "clone" 
                    });

                $("#content").droppable({                
                    drop: function(event, ui) {
                        $("#content").append("<img id='finishImage' src='as.jpg'/>");
                    }
                });
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Im doing Drag & Drop from `div pallette` to `div content`.
Everything good but. I want to do this drop mouse location. Like window builder. 
My code is always drop position x:0 y:0 like this:
[image]

How can i do "drop mouse location".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added this to your JS

```
$("#content").droppable({                
                drop: function(event, ui) {
                  var pos = $("#content").position()
                  $("#content").append("<img id='finishImage' src='as.jpg' style='left: "+(event.pageX-pos.left)+"px; top: "+(event.pageY-pos.top)+"px'/>");
                }
              });
```

and this to your CSS

```
#content #finishImage{
 position :absolute
}
```

I added a top and left style attribute to the picture when its added which is judged form the mouse location (`pageX/pageY`) and accounts for the location of the Div(`position.left/.top`)

[Heres a codePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EvYajx?editors=1010) with movable objects

Comment: U are the best!!

Comment: and can I ask something about this code? How can I drag clones in <div id=content>

Comment: i don't understand

Comment: basically i want to move clones in content divension.

Comment: Yes but dropped items doesnt have draggable feature when i drop it

Answer (score 0):

Hello there is a [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nmalloul/zxswcjav/) simple code that i wrote couple weeks ago.

I wish it will resolve your problem.

```js
$('.startEventClass').draggable({
  helper: "clone",
});

$('.userTaskClass').draggable({
  helper: "clone",
});

$('.endEventClass').draggable({
  helper: "clone",
});

$('#diagramZone').droppable({
  accept: ".startEventClass, .userTaskClass, .endEventClass",
  drop: function(e, ui) {
    dragE1 = ui.helper.clone();
    dragE1.draggable({
      containment: "#diagramZone",
    });
    $(dragE1).removeClass("startEventClass");
    $(dragE1).addClass("startEventClass");
    if (ui.draggable[0].id) {
      dragE1.appendTo('#diagramZone');
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.startEventClass {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border: solid 2px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.userTaskClass {
  width: 120px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border: solid 2px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.endEventClass {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border: solid 5px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

#diagramZone {
  height: 200px;
  border: solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="startEvent" class="startEventClass">

</div>

<div id="userTask" class="userTaskClass"></div>

<div id="endEvent" class="endEventClass"></div>




<div id="diagramZone" class="col-md-8" id="diagramZone">
</div>
```